# Add class to closest input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello i am trying to add a class to the closest input field. 
but the class never gets added.

Here is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    xaxa = '';

    $("input[name=handle_value]:radio").click(function() {
        self.parent.parent.xaxa = $(this).val();
    });

    $("#close").click(function() {
        parent.$.fancybox.close();
    });
    $("a#handle").fancybox({
        'type': 'iframe',
        'beforeLoad': function() {
            $(this).closest('.handlefield').addClass('handle-change');
        },
        'afterClose': function() {
            $('.handle-change').val(xaxa);
            $('.handlefield').removeClass('handle-change');
        },
    });
});
```

HTML :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">{% trans %}Houder{% endtrans %}</label>
         <div class="col-sm-2">
              <div class="input-group">
                   <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i></span>
                                {{ form_widget(form.registerProfileRegistrant, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control handlefield', 'value': profile.pdbRegisterProfileRegistrantHandle } }) }} 
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><a id="handle" href="{{ path('iframe') }}"><i class="fa fa-link fa-fw"></i></a></span>
               </div>
          </div>
</div>
```

inputfield generated html by twig :

`<input type="text" id="profile_registerProfileRegistrant" name="profile[registerProfileRegistrant]" class="form-control handlefield" value="PTG0000003">`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "input field"? i don't see any `<input>` in there..?

Comment: @TilwinJoy, it's probably (and yes, I am guessing) generated by whatever template engine he uses (Twig?)

Comment: <input type="text" id="profile_registerProfileRegistrant" name="profile[registerProfileRegistrant]" class="form-control handlefield" value="PTG0000003">

Comment: I am using twig and symfony 2. forgot to mention !

Comment: @tommie please update the question with the info instead of dumping it in comments, which is unreadable...

Answer (score 1):

`.closest()` only works for parents elements, it won't travel through the full DOM tree.

So, get back to the closest `.input-group`, then search for your input in children with `.find()` :

```
$("a#handle").fancybox({
    'type': 'iframe',
    'beforeLoad': function() {
        $(this).closest('.input-group').find('.handlefield').addClass('handle-change');
    },
    'afterClose': function() {
        $('.handle-change').val(xaxa);
        $('.handlefield').removeClass('handle-change');
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts this worked for me :

`$(this).parents(".input-group").find('.handlefield').addClass('handle-change');`